# C++ sigslot: Emit signal in the slot

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, thread-safety

Currently I'm working on a project that uses a library from http://sigslot.sourceforge.net/.

I try to understand the detail explanation of the concept so that I can easily utilizes the library. However I can't get much information about that.

Right now I have a slot. Inside the slot function I want to check a condition. If the condition is fail I want to enter the slot function again and keep recheck the condition until it pass.

**I wonder if I can emit signal inside the slot? Is this a proper way to do so?**

At first I just emit the signal (that connect the slot) and when I run I face software crash. When I debug, I found that the signal is emitted a lot of time which might cause the crash.

Then I play around by put 1msec sleep before emit the signal. By this, I don't face software crash. However, I only run using a simulator which showing the ideal running condition without hardware. Thus putting 1msec sleep is not flexible.

```
void TestRunningSlot(int a, int b)
{
   if (x is satisfy)
   {
      // Set flag - done with the slot
   }
   else
   {
      // Sleep(1000); // will crash without Sleep
      TestRunningSignal.emit(a, b);
   }
}
```

My questions are, when emit the signal, do software need to give a time to run the slot or my guess is correct about a heap of signal being emit can cause trouble? Do software need to wait for something before emitting again? Do I implement correctly?

Comment: Maybe `emit` call just invokes the connected slot `TestRunningSlot` again and the crash is just stack overflow error because they infinitely invoke each other? If you want to poll the condition infinitely without delays you can maybe just use the loop `while (! x is  not satisfy) do nothing`. Otherwise you maybe want some kind of event queue or just wait for condition with proper notification e.g. via [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable#Example)

Comment: Thanks! I did change my implementation to while(). At first using while can cause unrecoverable looping to the project which made me avoid using it. However now I find way to implement it properly. But still I have no answer for the sigslot question.